# Downloaded an older gem for rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Im taking over a project someone started a while ago. Im having a little bit of a difficult time because its Rails 2, and i have only learned rails 3.

Im trying to install a gem ive used frequently, but the newest version is for rails 3. The github page says for rails 2, use version .1. But i do not know how to install an older version (especially since rails 2 has no Gemfile)! Can someone help? Heres the github:https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/tree/0.4.9 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the config/environment.rb file and add a line such as this:

```
config.gem "hpricot", :version => '0.6'
```

Change gem name and version number to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can install using `gem install devise_ldap_authenticatable -v 0.4.1`

Or download the gem [here](http://rubygems.org/downloads/devise_ldap_authenticatable-0.4.1.gem) and install using `gem install devise_ldap_authenticatable-0.4.1.gem --local`

For other versions click here: http://rubygems.org/gems/devise_ldap_authenticatable/versions